# Enter Key Behaviour in JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

How can the code be modified below such that when the enter key is also pressed, the jQuery date picker will react and set the variable (datePickerValue) to the date thats automatically highlighted anyway that being the present date when jQuery is opened up. Id like to be able to open the datepicker, hit the enter key quickly and it will just take the present day and store it into the var.

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- LOAD JQUERY LIBRARY: -->  
    <link   href="jq/jquery-ui.css"         type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jq/jquery.min.js"          type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="jq/jquery-ui.min.js"       type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

                $('#dd').dialog({ 
                                    autoOpen:   true,
                                    modal:      true,
                                    overlay:    { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'},
                                    title:      'Select the date:',
                                    height:     215, 
                                    width:      234,
                                    draggable:  false, 
                                    resizable:  false

                });//end of dialog_atip


var datePickerValue = ""

$("#d1").show().unbind().datepicker().datepicker("show").change(function ()  {  
   //$('#d1').datepicker({onSelect:datePickerValue = $(this).val() }).hide();
   $('#d1').datepicker({onSelect:datePickerValue = $(this).val() })
   alert("You picked: " + datePickerValue);
   $("#dd").dialog("close")
});



}//end of window.onload


</script>


</head>

<body>
<div style="display:none" id="dd">
<div id="d1">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you can do is, add a listener on #d1 for keycode == 13, and click present link on enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active element has the class `.ui-state-active` so you can simulate a click on that element when the enter key is pressed, like this:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e){
    if(e.which == 13)
    {
        $('.ui-state-active').click();
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hUsU/). Focus has to be on the document for it to work there (click anywhere on the output, then press the enter key).

Comment: This works great. However, is there a way to make it such that the enter key will only work when the focus is on the dialog window and not the entire html document?

Comment: Sure, since the dialog is modal, you can just check if it's open. `if(e.which === 13 && $('#dd').dialog('isOpen') === true)` http://jsfiddle.net/9hUsU/3/